# Chrome's error message is too silent

Tags: google-chrome

When I visit erroneous website with IE it alerts me errors if I set to do that. On the contarary, Chrome is too silent so I can't notice errors until I open the Inspector. This is usually better but it's not good when I'm developing websites.

Can I change this?

Comment: Well, obviously you can just leave the developer tools *open* on the console tab when you're developing.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @Kirk Woll's idea is really the way you'd want to go (I personally find the IE script errors painfully annoying)...

But there is a Chrome extension ([Javascript Errors Notifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jafmfknfnkoekkdocjiaipcnmkklaajd)) that is designed to notify you of script errors...maybe that is what you are after.